# Strange issue with regex matching in perl, alternate attempts match

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following perl script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 my $str = 'not-found=1,total-found=63,ignored=2';

 print "1. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
 print "2. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
 print "3. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
 print "4. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);

 print "Bye!\n";
```

The output after running this is:

```
1. matched using regex
3. matched using regex
Bye!
```

The same regex matches once and does not match immediately after. Any idea why the alternate attempts to match the same string with the same regex fail in perl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `m` and `g` as modifiers to your regex, they aren't doing what you want.

```
print "1. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ /total-found=(\d+)/);
print "2. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ /total-found=(\d+)/);
print "3. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ /total-found=(\d+)/);
print "4. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ /total-found=(\d+)/);
```

Specifically, the `m` is optional in this context `m/foo/` is exactly the same as `/foo/`.  The real problem is that `g` does a bunch of things you don't want in this context.  See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) for details.

Comment: The m can stay in the picture. It is redundant but doesn't hurt. The parentheses (all of them) can go.

Comment: Good point @imran - no need to use the capturing brackets... I'm guessing in the actual code stony_dreams is using that information though!

Comment: I wanted the parentheses because I need the extract the number. Removing the 'g' flag from the end did fix it. I am still confused as to why the exact same condition would fail alternatively when using the 'g' flag. Any idea what 'g' is doing to cause this behavior? In my actual script the '$str' is a long multiline string which is why I was using the 'g' flag.

Comment: @stony_dreams - read the documentation - using the `g` flag in this context lets you iterate through the captured matches with successive calls to the `$str =~/...../g`

Comment: Thanks, that really helps, I wanted /m instead of /g.

Comment: @stony_dreams: You don't want `/m` either, as it affects only the behaviour of the `^` and `$` anchors and you are using neither.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the long *explanation* why your code doesn't work.

The `/g` modifier changes the behaviour of the regex to “global matching”. This will match all occurrences of the pattern in the string. However, how this matching is done depends on *context*. The two (main) contexts in Perl are *list context* (the plural) and *scalar context* (the singular).

In **list context**, a global regex match returns a list of all matched substrings, or a flat list of all matched captures:

```
my $_ = "foobaa";
my $regex = qr/[aeiou]/;

my @matches = /$regex/g; # match all vowels
say "@matches"; # "o o a a"
```

In **scalar context**, the match *seems* to return a perl boolean decribing whether the regex matched:

```
my $match = /$regex/g;
say $match; # "1" (on failure: the empty string)
```

However, the regex turned into an *iterator*. Each time the regex match is executed, the regex starts at the current position in the string, and tries to match. If it matches, it returns true. If the match fails, then

- the match returns false, and
- the current position in the string is set to the start.

Because the position in the string was reset, the next match will suceed again.

```
my $match;
say $match while $match = /$regex/g;
say "The match returned false, or the while loop would have go on forever";
say "But we can match again" if /$regex/g;
```

The second effect — resetting the position — can be cancelled with the additional `/c` flag.

The position in a string can be accessed with the `pos` function: `pos($string)` returns the current position, which can be set like `pos($string) = 0`.

The regex can also be anchored with the `\G` assertion at the current position, much like `^` anchores a regex at the start of the string.

This `m//gc`-style matching makes it easy to write a tokenizer:

```
my @tokens;
my $_ = "1, abc, 2 ";
TOKEN: while(pos($_) < length($_)) {
  /\G\s+/gc and next; # skip whitespace
  # if one of the following matches fails, the next token is tried
  if    (/\G(\d+)/gc) { push @tokens, [NUM => $1]}
  elsif (/\G,/gc    ) { push @tokens, ['COMMA'  ]}
  elsif (/\G(\w+)/gc) { push @tokens, [STR => $1]}
  else { last TOKEN } # break the loop only if nothing matched at this position.
}
say "[@$_]" for @tokens;
```

Output:

```
[NUM 1]
[COMMA]
[STR abc]
[COMMA]
[NUM 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 my $str = 'not-found=1,total-found=63,ignored=2';

 print "1. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
```

matches `total-found=63` and `pos($str)` for the next match attempt is set to offset 26.

```
 print "2. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
```

matches `nothing` and therefor `pos($str)` is reset to offset 0.

That's why

```
 print "3. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
```

matches again `total-found=63` and `pos($str)` for the next match attempt is set again to offset 26 and that's why

```
 print "4. matched using regex\n" if ($str =~ m/total-found=(\d+)/g);
```

fails again like the second one, restteing `pos($str)` to offset 0.

```
 print "Bye!\n";
```