# Why does =~ only evaluate once?

Tags: regex, perl

In this example script:

```
#perl 5.26.1 
$foo = "batcathat";

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

This will print:

```
yes
no
```

The expected output is:

```
yes
yes
```

I can confirm by printing the string that it has not been mutated by running the regex match.

Why does Perl seemingly only evaluate a regex expression once? I could find no information about this on Google or manuals, and the behaviour is not intuitive to me. I expect that each time you evaluate a regex match, it starts from fresh, and does not remember anything about the previous match.

**Edit**: For future context, this question was asked after I found a bit of code looking like this:

```
while ( $foo =~ /pattern/g) { $some_incrementing_var++ };
```

I did not understand initially how this while loop could ever terminate, as on first glance it looked like an infinite loop.

Comment: "Not reproducible or caused by a typo" - Would someone care to explain? I have observed the same behaviour in two different perl interpreters.

Comment: You'll also get expected output if you concatenate an empty string onto `$foo` after the 1st `if` statement.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Strange issue with regex matching in perl, alternate attempts match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818111/strange-issue-with-regex-matching-in-perl-alternate-attempts-match)?

Comment: Good dupe @Ivar - the accepted answer to that question is extremely helpful. So `m//g` in scalar context creates an iterator, from what I understand.

Comment: @Lou, most _[scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)_ will offer this.

Comment: I see you got explanations from ikegami about scalar-context use of the `/g` modifier (the problem in the question), but here are also doc links for basics [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Global-matching) and for some clear statements [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Matching-in-list-context) as well.

Comment: The global flag is meaningless here, since you only need one occurrence `if($foo =~ /cat/)` to determine the true/falsy of the check.

Comment: @sln That's true sln, but the edit to my question should clarify the reason for asking - I first noticed the `/g` flag in a while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/g` in scalar context is one of my favorite tools, and it's documented at unusual length in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators). That seems a weird place for it's docs, but there are flags that affect how the match operator works, and there are flags that affect how the pattern works (see [Know the difference between regex and match operator flags](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/04/know-the-difference-between-regex-and-match-operator-flags/)).

@ikegami mentions `pos`, which you can read about in [perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#pos-SCALAR). Perl tracks where it is in the a string. Without `/g` in scalar context, the match operator starts at the beginning of the string and moves toward the end. After it matches, it's done. The next match starts at the beginning of the string again.

The `\g` changes this slightly. The first match starts at the beginning of the string, matches (if it can), and set the position one after where the match ended. That's the `pos`. The next time with `\g`, the match starts at `pos`. In your case,

In list context, it's doing the same thing, but going to exhaustion. It makes the first match, then tries the next match starting at that position. This is why a match in list context cannot find overlapping matches: it starts matching after where the overlap would have started. Jeffrey Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/), despite being old, is a good survey of how regexes work, different ways they could work, and how various ways preclude features that other ways might have.

```
use v5.26;

my $foo = "batcathat";

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0; # not started, so undef

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0;  # now is 6

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
pos is 0
yes
pos is 6
no
```

This position is tracked per string and is reset after a failed match with `\g` (just like other regex side effect variables):

```
use v5.26;

my $foo = "batcathat";

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0; # not started, so undef

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}

$foo =~ /dog/g;

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0;  # now is 0 again after failed match

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

The output shows that both attempts to find `cat` work because the `dog` attempt failed and reset `pos`:

```
pos is 0
yes
pos is 0
yes
```

But, there's a way to get around that too. The `/c` flag tells the match operator to not reset `pos` on failure:

```
use v5.26;

my $foo = "batcathat";

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0; # not started, so undef

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}

$foo =~ /dog/gc; # will not reset pos

say "pos is ", pos($foo) // 0;  # now is 6 because /c

if ($foo =~ /cat/g) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

Now you are back to the original output:

```
pos is 0
yes
pos is 6
no
```

This allows you do things like this very simple example. You can match for a certain thing, and if that doesn't work out, try something else without losing your place in the string:

```
use v5.26;

my $foo = "batcathat";

$foo =~ /bat/g;

if( $foo =~ /\Gmat/gc ) {
    do_mat_things();
} elsif( $foo =~ /\Gchat/gc ) {
    do_chat_things();
} elsif( $foo =~ /\Gcat/gc ) {
    do_cat_things();
}
```

This allows you to walk through the string in very complex situations and do things in the middle of matching. I think I have some examples in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org).

Answer (score 6):

`//g` in scalar context starts to match where the previous /g match ended. Since `cat` only occurs only once, it returns false to indicate there's no match the second time.

This is useful in a loop:

```
while ( /\w+/g ) {
   say $&;
}
```

We can use `pos` to we can see what's going on.

```perl
local $_ = "abc def ghi";
while ( ( say pos // 0 ), /\w+/g ) {
   say $&;
}
```

```
0
abc
3
def
7
ghi
11
```

But while this is useful in a loop, it it makes no sense as `if ( //g )` (unless you're unrolling a loop). What would it mean? "Check if it matches, and keep checking for more matches for no reason"??? Obviously, that makes no sense. Remove the `g` to prints `yes` twice.

Answer (score 2):

You get the expected output if you omit the `//g` ("global") modifier:

```
$foo = "batcathat";

if ($foo =~ /cat/) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}

if ($foo =~ /cat/) {
    print "yes\n";
} else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

I see no need to use `//g` in your code.  Refer to [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)